# How can attach to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve in a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution

I have a dll that other applications use.  It relies on a 3rd party dll that updates fairly regularly.  As long as the version I need or greater is present then I am happy.

But Visual Studio forces the exact version I need on the apps that use my dll.

I want to add an event handler to  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve so I can check for a later version and just use that.  But I don't know where to add it.

Most apps would put this in program.cs startup.  But a dll does not have that.

I would put it in a static constructor, but I have many classes that use this 3rd party dll.  It seems messy to put this event attach into each class.

Is there any other option?

Comment: Is the 3rd party DLL managed or unmanaged?  From the question I assume managed.

Comment: The .config file should handle that, no?

Comment: Alternatively, use a profiler with time stamps to see what tends to get hit first. If will be tough though for a very disjointed library.

Comment: @Chris Shain - Both mine and the 3rd party libraries are managed.

Comment: @leppie - But then I have to enforce my config options on the users of my DLL.

Comment: @leppie - the dll's classes can be used in part or in full.  It is mostly a collection of helper classes.  Sot it just depends on the apps as to which one is used first.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Hall has an example of doing this http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2006/08/appdomaincurrentdomainassemblyresolve.html:

```
private Assembly AssemblyResolveHandler(object sender,ResolveEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] assemblyDetail = e.Name.Split(',');
        string assemblyBasePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyBasePath + @"\" + assemblyDetail[0] + ".dll");
        return assembly;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed resolving assembly", ex);
    }
}
```

Make sure the assignment of the delegate to `AssemblyResolve` is done before you try to resolve the types you want to "redirect".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx shows and example of this.

Comment: Yes, but where do I attach to this?  A dll has no OnLoad method to let me get this attached before the failure happens.  (That is the point of the question.)

Comment: In terms of a dll, that dll would have to be loaded *before*  the types you want to redirect are loaded.  Without doing *that* in Main(), there's no way to guarantee that.  At which point, you're basically forced to do the event subscription in main.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [assembly binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Foo.Bar" publicKeyToken="***" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.1"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is the best solution.  I don't like it because it forces the apps that use my dll to deal with the fact that I don't have the same version as they do (I would like my code to not cause any headaches for those who forget to do this).